# How to Write/Input Text inside a <P> tag in HTML in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I have an Iframe with a P tag in it. That P tag is where you can write a text using the keyboard. But using 'Input Text' seems not to work in in since Input text does not identify P tag as a text input field. Did anybody happened to experience the same situation?

Ive tried reading similar post but it seems to be irrelevant to my issue.

```
Enter Message
    element should be visible           id=cke_mail-editor-template-add
    select frame                        xpath=//*[@id="cke_1_contents"]/iframe
    wait until element is visible       xpath=/html/body/p[1]
    input text                          xpath=/html/body/p[1]
    ...                                 Test message
```

Below is the Element:

```
/html[1]/body[@class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr pastable pastable-focus"]/p[1]
```

> Expected Result: should be able to enter text
>
> Actual Result: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not
>   interactable

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the html code? As far as I know, text cannot be entered in a `<p>` tag.

Comment: this is the snippet.

/html[1]/body[@class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr pastable pastable-focus"]/p[1]

Comment: It's quite possible the element that should be targeted is below the `p` tag in the DOM. You have to look for the one that has the "contenteditable" attribute set - this makes a regular non-input element user-editable.